# What is this error that I'm getting with AVKit?

Tags: macos, runtime-error, avfoundation, mp4, avkit

I'm making a macOS AVKit app and I'm getting this error when playback of an mp4 finishes: `Project[8921:947130] GVA error: scheduleDecodeFrame kVTVideoDecoderBadDataErr nal err : acc_size = 5, datasize = 5, video_nal_count = 0,` What on earth does this mean? It seems to say that the video data is bad, but it plays just fine on Quicktime.

Comment: @A Tyshka did you able to resolve this?,i am also facing same problem

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem. Have you guys managed to solve it?